# Why does this code produce the output 513?

Tags: c, pointers

i saw this question at my c language final exam and the output is 513 and i don't know why

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    char a[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    print("%d" , *(short*)a);
}
```

Comment: Time to learn about bits, computer words, how longer data-types are stored on your system, and about [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: What value do you *think* it would print, and why?

Comment: @hero1780 In general the code has undefined behavior because it is not necessary that the character array is aligned as a short number.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code has undefined because on some platforms it will just crash with a SIGBUS.

Comment: What if the final exam question starts with, *"On our processor, in our classroom environment, assume this code is run....what is the output?"*?  Now the behavior is no longer undefined; it is implementation specified.

Comment: @abelenky How so? Do you know any compiler that documents a behavior for this code?

Comment: in the exam it just says "what will it print when the given code block  runs? " i did run it on my computer and the output is 513 @abelenky

Comment: In that case, @melpomene is correct:  The code may put out anything or nothing, it may crash your computer or [erase your drive](https://blog.tchatzigiannakis.com/undefined-behavior-can-literally-erase-your-hard-disk/).  The best you can say is that the output ***might reasonably*** be `513`; but it could be anything.

Answer (score 7):

Your array of bytes is (in hex):

```
[ 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 ]
```

If you treat the start of the array not as an array of bytes, but as the start of a `short`, then your short has value `0x01 0x02`, and because your processor is ["Little Endian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), it reads backwards from how humans read it.  We would it as `0x0201`, which is the same as `513(Decimal)`

Comment: This also assumes `sizeof (short) == 2`.

Comment: @melpomene:  We don't have the full context of hero1780's final exam, but that seems like a pretty safe assumption.

Comment: @abelenky you should include something like this in your answer: "assuming sizeof short is 2 and assuming there are no alignement issues on your platform". Upvoted anyway.

Comment: @Jabberwocky the OP question contains "_the output is 513_" so it is not an assumption to say _short_ are on 2 bytes, it is a fact

Comment: ""Little Endian", it reads backwards from how humans read it. "  --> fun counter example: 17 is read as seventeen. (seven and ten).

Comment: @chux English joke not easy to translate ^^

Comment: @chux Probably a vestige of English's Germanic origins.  23 is "drei und zwanzig" which would literally translate to "three and twenty"

Answer (score 4):

If the system this code is being run on meets the following requirements:

- Unaligned memory access is permitted (or `a` is guaranteed to be `short`-aligned)
- Little-endian byte order is used
- `sizeof(short) == 2`
- `CHAR_BIT == 8`

Then  dereferencing a `short *` pointer to the following memory:

```
|  0x01  |  0x02  |  0x03  |  0x04  |
```

Will give you `0x0201`, or `513` in base 10.

Also, do note that even if all these requirements are met, aliasing a `char []` array as a `short *` violates the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Comment: The code also requires unaligned access to integers (or a compiler that aligns `a` on a two-byte boundary). The format specifier is fine: `short` is implicitly converted to `int` when passed to a varargs function.

Comment: I would also add something about using `-fno-strict-aliasing`, since this is an aliasing violation regardless of alignment.

Comment: @melpomene *The format specifier is fine: short is implicitly converted to `int` when passed to a varargs function.*  A bit late here, but that format specifier does have problems, as the promotion of `short` to `int` might very well sign extend the `short`.

Answer (score 1):

The code casts your `char*` pointer into `short*` one and prints its value.

short in C is represented in 2 bytes, and the binary representation of the first two bytes of your array is `00000001 00000010` but because the processor is a little endian one it reads it as `00000010 00000001` which is 513 in decimal.

Comment: `short` in C must be at least 16 bits, but it may be more than two bytes. It can even be one byte in an implementation in which a byte is at least 16 bits. It is not true that it is necessarily two bytes.